# Remove part numbering in backmatter

Tags: book-design, parts, scrbook

I want part numbering in the `\backmatter` to behave like chapters do (no numbering but included in ToC).

I'm using `scrbook` as my document class.

Comment: `\backmatter\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}` should do the trick. However I can't see the use of parts in the backmatter.

Comment: Any reason to not just post that comment as an answer so I can mark this question as answered?

Comment: Laziness: I was waiting that you tested it. `;-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you say

```
\backmatter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
```

then you inhibit numbering at any level. The action can be made automatic in the preamble by saying

```
% turning off part numbering in the backmatter
% parts will still go to the TOC
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\backmatter{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}}
\makeatother
```

It's better, if possible, to have setup code in the preamble rather than scattered in the document, so it will be easier to control it and change one's mind later by just commenting one line in the preamble.

I'm still dubious about the usefulness of dividing the backmatter into parts.